# In Javascript how can I stop any further iterations from firing until a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

I have been trying to get the following issue resolved for the past 2 weeks and am getting nowhere, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction;

I have a single page application that uses JS and jQuery alongwith xml logic conditions and actions.

With JS allowing for functions to act asynchronously is great but I need to solve an issue;

When a user clicks an element the js goes through the xml and finds nodes related to the element ID, checks if the condition set is met and fires associated actions. A snippet of XML iis shown below;

```
 <block id="10000005" triggerID="125">
  <ConditionsAndActions name="Default" setIndex="0">
   <Conditions>
   </Conditions>
   <Actions>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="AskForConfirmation" message="Are you sure?"/>
    <Action actionIndex="0" type="NewRecord" />
   </Actions>
  </ConditionsAndActions>
 </block>
```

The abiove indicates when '#btn125' is clicked  fire AskForConfirmation function then if user clicks the confirmation button, process the manual record function.

The actions are traversed by a loop and I need to for AskForConfirmation stop the loop continuing until either user completed acknowledgement or if user gives a negative response or a 30 second period lapses then the loop is abandoned.

I have tried setTimeout using a variable to control firing the next action without success and cannot get my head around async/await if this is feasable please guide me on how to do it.

I include the action firing loop below;

```
 function triggerActions(callType, tags, iC1, iC2, iC3, iC4) {
    for (var iA1 = 0; iA1 < tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes.length; iA1++) {
        if (tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].nodeName === "Actions") {
            for (var iA2 = 0; iA2 < tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes.length; iA2++) {
                if ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("type") !== null) {
                    switch ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("type")) {
                        case "ChangeVisibility":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : ' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("element") + ' visibility amended.');
                            }
                            eval('$("#' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("element") + '").' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].chidNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("effect") + '();');
                            break;
                        case "commentBox":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Comment box for ' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("name") + ' found in configuration');
                                loggingAction('log','comment log');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "DisplayAlert":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Lightbox stating: ' + variableConversion(($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("message"))) + ' output');
                            }
                            var alertMessage = '<h2 class="text-center">ALERT:</h2><p class="text-center">' + variableConversion(($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("message"))) + '</p>';
                            $.colorbox({
                                html: alertMessage
                            });
                            $('#cboxContent').removeClass('errorMessage');
                            break;
                        case "DataQuery":
                            if (debugMode && (($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destination")).length !== 0)) {
                                destination = '{{' + ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destination")) + '}}';
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Data Query initiated with destination = "' + destination + '", destinationControl = "' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destinationControl") + '",query number = "' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("queryNumber") + '", parameters ="' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("parameters") + ' " and values = "' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("values") + '".');
                            }
                            getRunQuery($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destination"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destinationControl"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("parameters"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("queryNumber"), sessionID);
                            break;
                        case "DataSource":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Data Source Action');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "DispositionCall":
                            sendDisposition($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("outcome"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("callbackNumber"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("callbackNumberControl"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("callbackTime"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("callbackTimeControl"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("personalCallback"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("returnData"));
                            break;
                        case "GetRecord":
                            var URN = ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2])).attr("URN");
                            if (gridValueSelected.length > 0) {
                                URN = gridValueSelected;
                            }
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('info','INFORMATION : Get Record request initiated with URN return of "' + URN + '".');
                            }
                            rid = generateRID(), message = 'type: "GetRecord", RID: ' + rid + ', SID: ' + sessionID + ', URN:"' + URN + '"';
                            activeRequests.push(rid + ':GetRecord');
                            socket.send(message);
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('info','INFORMATION : Get Record message sent to server  "' + message + '".');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "GoAvailable":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                if (debugMode) { loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Setting Agent status to Available.'); }
                                rid = generateRID(), message = 'type:"GoAvailable",RID:' + rid + ',SID:' + sessionID;
                                serverComms("outbound", message, rid, "GoAvailable");
                                if (debugMode) { loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Message sent to server - "' + message + '".'); }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "HangUp":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Hang up call requested.');
                            }
                            $.colorbox({
                                html: '<h2 class="confirmation text-center">Confirmation:</h2><p class="confirmation text-center">Call hung up.</p>'
                            });
                            $('#cboxContent').removeClass('errorMessage');
                            break;
                        case "LogOut":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Agent has requested to Log out of script.');
                            }
                            logOut();
                            break;
                        case "MoveToPanel":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Action to Move to Panel #pnl' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + ' triggered.');
                            }
                            var parser = new DOMParser(),
                                xmlLogic = parser.parseFromString(scriptXML, "text/xml"),
                                tags = xmlLogic.getElementsByTagName('*');
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                for (var i0 = 1; i0 < tags.length; i0++) {
                                    switch (tags[i0].nodeName) {
                                        case "Button":
                                            updateVariableOutput('#' + $(tags[i0]).attr("id"), $(tags[i0]).attr("name"));
                                            break;
                                        case "inputField":
                                            updateVariableOutput('#' + $(tags[i0]).attr("id"), $(tags[i0]).attr("label"));
                                            break;
                                        case "textBlock":
                                            updateVariableOutput('#' + $(tags[i0]).attr("id"), $(tags[i0]).attr("text"));
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            eval('$("#pnl' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + '").parent().children().hide(); $("#pnl' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + '").show();');
                            gridValueSelected = '';
                            $('.selectedRow').removeClass('selectedRow');
                            $('table').children().remove();
                            $('table').removeClass('jsgrid');
                            break;
                        case "MoveToScriptWindow":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION :Action to Move to Window "#win' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + '" has been triggered.');
                            }
                            eval('$("#win' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + '").parent().children().hide(); $("#win' + $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("panelID") + '").show();');
                            gridValueSelected = '';
                            $('.selectedRow').removeClass('selectedRow');
                            $('table').children().remove();
                            $('table').removeClass('jsgrid');
                            break;
                        case "OpenBrowserWindow":
                            openNewWindow($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("URL"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("toolbar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("addressBar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("toolbar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("addressBar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("toolbar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("addressBar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("toolbar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("addressBar"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("width"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("height"));
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','INFORMATION : "' + variableConversion($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("URL")) + '" opened in new window.');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "SetFieldParameter":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Field Parameter Set');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "SetTextBox":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Set Text Box Action');
                            }
                            break;
                        case "SetVariable":
                            if (gridValueSelected !== '') {
                                var variableName = $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("variable")
                                if (debugMode) {
                                    loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : The variable to have selected grid value associated with it is "' + variableName + '".');
                                }
                                variableNameSplit = variableName.split('.');
                                if (debugMode) {
                                    loggingAction('info','INFORMATION : The Object to recieve the variable is "' + variableNameSplit[1] + '".');
                                    loggingAction('info','INFORMATION : The key for the variable is "' + variableNameSplit[1] + '".');
                                }
                                if ((variableNameSplit[0] === 'Script') || (variableNameSplit[0] === 'SCRIPT')) {
                                    addScriptVariable(variableNameSplit[1], gridValueSelected);
                                }
                            } else {
                                loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : Set Variable Value function initiated.');
                                if ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("value") !== '') {
                                    var variableName = $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("variable"),
                                        variableValue = variableConversion($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("value"));
                                    if (debugMode) {
                                        loggingAction('log','NOTIFICATION : ' + variableName + ' set to "' + variableValue + '".');
                                    }
                                    eval(variableName + '="' + variableValue + '"');
                                } else if ($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("controlID") !== '') {
                                    var variableName = $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("variable"),
                                        variableValue = $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("controlID");
                                    variableValue = eval('$("#txt' + variableValue + '").val()');
                                    if (debugMode) {
                                        loggingAction('log',' NOTIFICATION : The value of the variable to be passed to ' + variableName + ' is "' + variableValue + '".');
                                    }
                                    eval(variableName + '="' + variableValue + '"');
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case "UpdateWebFrame":
                            if (debugMode) {
                                loggingAction('info','INFORMATION : iFrame update initiated to load ' + variableConversion($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("URL")) + '.')
                            }
                            updateIFrame($(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("URL"), $(tags[0].childNodes[iC1].childNodes[iC2].childNodes[iC3].childNodes[iA1].childNodes[iA2]).attr("destinationControl"));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A simplified example of what I'm looking to achieve is below;

JS;

```
var blocker = 'no';

function askForConfirmation() {
    $('#Interaction').fadeIn();
}
function manualRecord() {
console.log('Request new record')}
function responseReceived(acknowledgemntValue){
    $('#Interaction').fadeOut();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn69').click(function(){
        askForConfirmation();    
    });
    $('#accept').click(function(){
        blocker = 'no';
        responseReceived();
        alert(blocker);
    });
    $('#decline').click(function(){
        blocker = 'yes';
        responseReceived();
        alert(blocker);
    });
});
```

html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Sandbox testing</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
        <button id="btn69">Request Manual Record</button>
        <div id="Interaction" style="display:none;">
        <p>Please confirm you wish to create manual record</p>
        <p><button id="accept">Accept</button><button id="decline">Decline</button></p>
        </div>
        <div id="blockerState"></div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="sandscript.js"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate the code above is missing the AskForConfirmation switch case;

Comment: It simpy sets a variable to 'waiting', pops up a lightbox with a question and yes / no buttons then loops with setTimeout until variable is updated by user clicking one of the buttons or 30 seconds passes

Comment: You'll likely get more responses if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. The act of creating that may help in and of itself.

Comment: Agreed with the above. This is too much code to go through. My initial assessment though is that you could set a flag to determine if your functions should continue. If that flag is ever true, don't run the function and, if you would like, attempt to run it again 30 seconds from that point. If at that point the flag is still true, cease execution.

Comment: aside: you should not use `childNodes` to consume xml/html because it's very fragile and can break on tiny differences like different whitespace interpretations on different browsers. Use tag names and long selectors, CSS or XPATH for shorter, more relaivle, and longer-lasting data consumption.

Comment: @dandavis this is something on my radar but the current code is reasonably resilient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the issue by tracking the action number and adding a counter mechanism to track status which is updated on action completion then fires the next action

Comment: Can you provide a snippet to show how you achieved this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

**Loop won't pause for async operation(like setTimeout) to be completed** This is just how JavaScript(single threaded language) executes the statement. Therefore `setTimeout` in a loop is not going to work.

Though Its not clear why you are putting the logic of `triggerActions` inside `for` loop if it is just a single action of button click and probably only one corresponding action from xml will get triggered.

Whatever the scenario or business requirement you have may be you can tweak the `triggerActions` as below to get it working in current scenario.

The idea is to store the indexes with which the `for` loop to be resumed when you wait for user for particular condition and then call the `triggerActions` again to resume the loop from where it was left.

```js
var startIndexOuterLoop, startIndexInnerLoop; //hold the reference of for loop index for the `AskForConfirmation` scenario

function triggerActions(params..., resumeMode) {

  var iA1, iA2;
  if (resumeMode) {
    iA1 = startIndexOuterLoop;
    iA2 = startIndexInnerLoop;
  } else {
    iA1 = 0;
    iA2 =
  }
  var outerLoopIterateOnce = false;
  for (; i < ...; i++) {
    //reset iA2 to 0 onward, right
    if (outerLoopIterateOnce) {
      iA2 = 0;
    }

    outerLoopIterateOnce = true;
    for (; i < ...; i++) {
      // ... statements

      if ( /*condition for AskForConfirmation */ ) {
        handleAskForConfirmation(iA1, iA2);
        return; //exit from function
      }


    }

  }

}

function handleAskForConfirmation(iA1, iA2) {
  startIndexOuterLoop = iA1+1;//1 added so as to continue next iteration
  startIndexInnerLoop = iA2+1;
  // add logic for wait time out etc
  //once thats expired or as per business logic call triggerActions again with one more parameter as true to resume the foor loop indirectly
  triggerActions(params..., true);
}
```

Comment: Amitesh, if I'm understanding correctly what this in effect does is store the array or object of values and exits the loop. then once ready to continue returns the the point in the loop where I was previously using the array or object values?

Comment: Ya right.. but  just remembering indexes of the loop is sufficient to resume.. no need to store entire state(object array etc) of the function

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: I removed the issue by tracking the action number and adding a counter mechanism to track status which is updated on action completion then fires the next action